# I want to remove Framesets and Iframes and still have page refresh PHP data independently without refreshing the whole page

Tags: php, audio, iframe, frameset, audio-player

I am learning PHP and I am trying to get my new audio player to work in PHP.

Any web designers out there that can help me [with my page](http://chennaichristianradio.com/PHP/web/player.html)?

I need the player at the bottom to continue playing, while the data on the right and left (above) update independently. At the same time I want the page title when the music does.

80% has been written, but I know it can be done better. My goal is to remove the iframes and Framesets and add the song title on the page title.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a server side technology so in order to make this work you will need to use something like AJAX. [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) makes AJAX requests relatively simple not to mention it is a powerful and lightweight Javascript library.